# How to simplify a sum of complex divisors?

Tags: complex-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, project-euler

This question arises from [Project Euler 153](https://projecteuler.net/problem=153).  That problem asks for the sum of all complex divisors of all natural numbers up to a maximum, where a complex divisor is a complex number of the form a + b*i where a is a positive integer and b is an integer.  I have solved the problem for divisors where b is zero (real divisors) so I only need to solve it for true complex divisors now.

I have simplified the problem as follows:

All true complex numbers with a positive real part can be written as $k(a \pm bi)$ with a, b, and k positive integers and a and b coprime.  Then there are two cases:

$a \neq b$:

$k(a - bi) \vert x$

Multiply through by the conjugate

$k(a^2 + b^2) \vert x(a + bi)$

Since a and b are coprime, $a + bi$ can be dropped.

$k(a^2 + b^2) \vert x$

Let $c = a^2 + b^2$

The sum of divisors of numbers less than n that are multiples of the complex number is
$$\sum \left\lfloor{n \over kc}\right\rfloor 2k(a + b)$$
because for every k there are $\left\lfloor{n \over kc}  \right\rfloor$ multiples of $a + bi$, $a - bi$, $b - ai$, and $b + ai$.  This last part allows us to only consider coprime pairs where a < b (so I can use Fairy sequences in my program).

$a = b$:

This case is exactly the same except since $a = b = 1$, $b \pm ai$ is the same as $a \pm bi$ so there is no need to count it twice and the sum is just
$$\sum \left\lfloor{n \over 2k}\right\rfloor 2k$$

The overall sum is therefore
$$
\left( \sum \left\lfloor{n \over 2k}\right\rfloor 2k \right) +
\left( \sum_{a \perp b \wedge a < b} \sum_k \left\lfloor{n \over kc}\right\rfloor 2k(a + b)\right)
$$

However, this does not work.  I've tested my program for n = 10 where the correct result should be 74 (161, found on [this site](http://forum.projecteuler.net/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=1927), minus 87, the sum of the real divisors), but I get 88.  Is my analysis incorrect or is there an error in my program?  I'm not sure about dropping $a + bi$: I know it would work for real numbers if their gcd is a unit like a b and i, but maybe not for complex numbers.

Comment: It turns out this analysis is correct I just forgot to actually use the function based on it.  Interestingly, the sum of multiples of the complex number dividing numbers less than n is equal to the sum of the real divisors of n divided by the magnitude of the complex number.